# OSGi doesn't launch selected bundles

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, equinox, fedora-25

When I launch OSGi framework with very few bundles selected in the Run Configurations, Eclipse (Oxygen) instead launches all available bundles and spews a bunch of errors. The first one is:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui 4 0 2017-04-13 09:46:50.669
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui [1142]
```

I have 1252 bundles in total in the list of bundles, but `ss` returns 1256 bundles. Can anyone shed a light on why is this so?

Added: config.ini

```
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:/home/../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.1.200.v20160504-1450.jar@1\:start
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
osgi.install.area=file\:/home/../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool
osgi.framework=file\:/home/../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.3.v20170209-1843.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:/home/../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/stable-test/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
osgi.configuration.cascaded=false
```

Comment: show your config.ini file content. This will be stored in your configuration Area folder. Check Configuration tab in run configuration.

Comment: Do not shorten the content instead edit your post and add whole content in question itself NOT in comment.

Comment: Thank you sir @ChandrayyaGK!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether plugin `org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui` present in **bungle.info** file(`org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file\:/home/../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/stable-test/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info`)

I think it is missing in your case, if so install this plugin in your eclipse installation. Then replace add **osgi.bundles** property as mentioned below in config.ini. Restart application.

> osgi.bundles=**org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui@1\:start**,reference:file:/home/../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.bundle_pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.1.200.v20160504-1450.jar@1:start`

Comment: That plugin is indeed missing there. Since then, I created a new launch configuration with exactly the same settings that worked just fine. In the working example the plugin `org.eclipse.epp.mpc.ui` is missing too though. After I switched to that non-working configuration and reset to the relevant commit in git, I can't reproduce that issue anymore and instead I get `!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.junit [216]
Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.hamcrest.core; bundle-version="1.3.0"; visibility:="reexport"`.

Comment: Go to `File > Export > Run/Debug > Launch configurations` and select your configuration, save it on your machine. After export you will get **.launch** file in the selected directory, open this file and copy the content then add it in your question/post for further analysis.